# Bash: Make a failed zip inverbose

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, zip, pipe

I use Ubuntu server 16.04 and I have this command to `mysqldump` all DB to stdout, which I then pipe into `zip`.

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip ${drt}/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip
```

If there are no databases in my root database, the command seem to fail and I get a very large verbose list of "zip warnings".

Why do I get these warnings and how could I prevent them (make the output inverbose)?

---

Note: `${drt}` stands for "document root" (`/var/www/html`).

Comment: Perhaps when `mysqldump`  command dumps nothing into the pipe and `zip` detects nothing to compress, it might warn you about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append `>/dev/null` to your zip command.